# How to connect scala to sqlite using slick 2.1?

Tags: sqlite, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I am trying to use slick 2.1 API but it's not working.  I have created an in memory database using the statement:

```
rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

I need to access this database in another thread (for reading data). Is there any way to access this in memory database in another thread?

The documentation says:

> Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two
>   database connections each with the filename :memory: will create two
>   independent in-memory databases.

Comment: By "another thread", do you mean "another process"? That looks like a line of C code you say you have executed, not Scala code. Are you not using JDBC?